# Group Already Exist

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $group_name = <STDIN>;
my $group_id = <STDIN>;
my $choice = <STDIN>;

  print "* My menu *\n";
  print "* *\n";
  print "* 1. Create a Unix Group  *\n";
  print "* 2. Delete a Unix Group  *\n";
  print "* 3. Create a Unix User *\n";
  print "* 4. Delete a Unix USer *\n";
  print "* 5. Quit *\n";
  print "* *\n";
  print "******************************************************\n";
  print "* Enter Your Choice >\n";

  $choice = <STDIN> ;

  chomp $choice;
  if ($choice == 1) {
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Create A Unix Group\n";
  print "**********************************\n";
  print " Enter The Group Name to Create >\n";
  chomp ($group_name = <STDIN>);
  print " Enter the Group ID to Create >\n";
  chomp ($group_id = <STDIN> );

  if ( ! 'grep -i $group_name /etc/group' ) {
      system ("groupadd -g $group_id $group_name");
  print "Group Created Successfully!\n"
      } else {
  print "Group Already Exists !\n";
      }
      }
```

When I run the script and enter the group id it comes back group already exist. It doesn't matter what I enter to be honest it keeps coming back Group already existed which I know the group doesn't exist. Any Suggestiongs?

Comment: gnouc's answer below is correct. An improvement that I would suggest is to change the line `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` to `grep $group_name: /etc/group`. With the -i option, you will match groups regardless of case, which is probably not your intention. By adding the colon, you stop matching groups that your desired group is a substring of. E.g. If you want to add the group `mail`, and the group `mailer` already exists, then your script as it currently stands will not permit the group `mail` to be added. My suggestion will stop this sort of issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is at line:

```
if ( ! 'grep -i $group_name /etc/group' )
```

Here you use quote `'...'`, so `perl` will treat it as literal string. String in boolean context, which is not null will be eveluated to true, so your `if` condition always fails, the `else` branch is executed.

To run system command from `perl`, you must use backsticks **`...`** or use `system()` builtin function:

```
if ( ! `grep -i $group_name /etc/group` )
```

Comment: its worked but why do I get this error4567
Can't exec "groupadd": No such file or directory at ./Menu3.pl line 34, <STDIN> line 6.
Group Created Successfully!

Comment: Change `groupadd -g $group_id $group_name` to `/bin/groupadd -g $group_id $group_name` or `/usr/bin/groupadd -g $group_id $group_name` and the erro will probably disappear.